# using jquery ui datepicker as inline calendar

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a set of unique requirements.  I need to be able to show an entire year with hte jquery ui datepicker and then when the user picks a date, change the background color of that date and add a record to a database.  This seems to work well until many dates are selected, then it seems to bog down.  Is there a way for jquery ui datepicker to only render the selected cell instead of the whole calendar when a date is selected?  Is there another calendar I should use for this tasik?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this:

```
<label>Multiple Month DatePicker: </label>
<input id="date" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var dt = {
            numberOfMonths: 12
        };
        $("#date").datepicker(dt);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works, but they have to select multiple dates and when a date is selected it seems the whole calendar is rerendered, thus causing performance issues when many dates are selected.  Not exactly sure what I can do to fix that.

Comment: hi i have some what same requirements with little difference i have to display month form jan to dec.